# How to input Unicode characters of which Unicode number exceeds 10000 in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

When coding QML, I usually input Unicode words via "\uxxxx". But it doesn't work for the characters of which Unicode number is over 10000, e.g. U+1F300. How to input it via Unicode number?

```
ToolButton {
    id: toolButton
    text: "\u1F300"
}
```

Comment: I believe this is related to the limitation of QChar: "Unicode characters with code values above 65535 are stored using surrogate pairs". So you will probably have to use 2 hex values, encoding the code point as low and high members of a surrogate pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the JS function [`String.fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint):

```
ToolButton {
    id: toolButton
    text: String.fromCodePoint(0x1F300)
}
```